# RASPI cannot detect LCD resistive eGalax Touchscreen

Tags: noobs

Hi i am facing a wierd problem , wherein the touchscreen resistive LCD which i was able to interface with RASPI is not at all detected by raspi now .
The Following post which i created earlier at www.raspberrypi.org helped me to do it .

viewtopic.php?f=91&t=90808&p=690427#p690427
Topic :Raspi with LCd touchscreen .

But out of nowhere the touch stopped working , "lsusb" command does not show D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalax TouchScreen .
But when connected the touchscreen LCD to ubuntu machine , lsusb shows D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalax TouchScreen although when i used xinput_calibrator command for calibration the touch points are not correctly detected .
But i am more worried about the RASPI not detecting the touchscreen H/W .I had two touchscreen both of them show up with ubuntu machine but not in RASPI .
when i run command .. udevadm monitor --udev on ubuntu machine on replugging the touchscreen USB PCB i get

```
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
```

On attaching USB touchscreen resistive screen .

```
UDEV [14457.318634] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
UDEV [14457.320794] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV [14457.321723] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/input/input29 (input)
UDEV [14457.323592] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/input/input29/mouse1 (input)
UDEV [14457.324103] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/input/input29/event10 (input)
```

On detaching USB touchscreen resistive screen .

```
UDEV [14470.833275] remove /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/input/input29/mouse1 (input)
UDEV [14470.860543] remove /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/input/input29/event10 (input)
UDEV [14470.884447] remove /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/input/input29 (input)
UDEV [14470.885016] remove /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV [14470.890673] remove /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
```

whereas when i do the same on RASPI .. it add the device and then removes it again and tries it multiple times even the screen flickers ..denoting touchevents detected ..i.e ..may be its stuck in a loop untill it finally stops .

Thanks .

Comment: If the screen is powered via USB and this is not a + or model 2, or you don't have at least a 2A supply, it probably cannot provide enough power.

Comment: I changed the power supply , i am basically using a mobile charger to power the raspi B+ , and now the eGalax H/w is detected through lsusb , it does not disconnect as earlier , however the touchscreen only detects the first touch event , after that nothing happens ,another interesting thing that happens is the mouse cursor goes to left top corner on first touch , i even  installed xinput_calibrator and dependencies , even while calibrating it detects only first touch , i tried using the mouse to detect the touch points , then it detects 3 touch calib points but calibration not sucessfull .